# Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000 not detected

Tags: 11.10, mouse, bluetooth

Ubuntu 11.10 cannot detect my Bluetooth Mouse at all (it doesn't appear at all using "Set up new device" after clicking on the Bluetooth icon at the top of the screen).

Obviously the wireless switch is ON and also the Bluetooth is ON. My PC is Sony Vaio VPCM13M1E. Anyone can help me please?

Comment: Did you pair your mouse with your computer?

Comment: How can I pair it if the mouse is not detected by Ubuntu?